# Android - Forecast.io - Retrofit - Set query when api doesn't require parameter name, just values

Tags: android, api, http-status-code-404, retrofit

I'm using Forecast.io to get the weather.
The api url is the following: 
    https://api.forecast.io/forecast/abf7afb3c49204d542b14e8ba282a188/37.8267,-122.423

**Call to the API**
    WeatherAPI.Factory.getmWeatherAPI().getWeather(48.8566,2.3522).enqueue(new Callback()

No name are required in the API url for longitude and latitude.

I'm trying this, but Retrofit seems to add special charaters - (see screen below)

```
@GET("forecast/")
    Call<Weather> getWeather(
            @Query("") Double longitude,
            @Query("") Double latitude);
```

The URL called is and leads to a 404

Thanks a lot for your help,

[image: Retrofit 404]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your url in log is wrong - you should swap "forecast" and your hash key "abf7afb3c49204d542b14e8ba282a188", so I guess you should change your `baseUrl` to `https://api.forecast.io` for example, when build a `Retrofit` object.

Secondly, the mistake is that you use `@Query` annotation, but it's not a query, it's a part of url path, so you should use `@Path` annotation, and your call should look like this (assuming, that your baseUrl is `https://api.forecast.io`):

```
@GET("/forecast/abf7afb3c49204d542b14e8ba282a188/{location}")
Call<Weather> getWeather(@Path("location") String location);
```

Then you can use this method by next way:

```
double lat = 48.8566;
double lng = 2.3522;
WeatherAPI.Factory.getmWeatherAPI().getWeather(lat + "," + lng).enqueue(new Callback());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. Tested and approved. Really!

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if it was helpful to you.